# "Сыграть" или "сиграть"?

Tags: орфография, корень-слова, чередования

Как правильно прибавлять приставку к корню, начинающемуся на И?

Comment: К ответам, данным ранее, добавлю исключение - взимать.

Comment: Мы как-то обсуждали этот вопрос в учительской. Я привела пример "подынтегральный". Почему-то он вызвал веселье у наших филологов.

Comment: Это оттого что интеграл ещё недостаточно обрусел.)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если приставка заканчивается на согласную букву, И в корне меняется на Ы.
Примеры: *играть - сыграть, искать - разыскать.*
И не меняется на Ы после иноязычных приставок: дез-, контр-, транс-, пан-.
Примеры: *трансинтернациональный, дезинформация*.