# Почему "сыграть" пишется через "ы", а не через "и"?

Tags: орфография, история, корень-слова, чередования

[Был уже](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/95/182097) похожий вопрос, но я немного не о том сейчас.

Само правило хорошо усвоил в школе и проблем с ним не испытываю. Пишу не задумываясь: иностранные приставки — "и", русские — "ы". Поэтому — когда и что применять — мне, в принципе, понятно.

А интересует меня, **почему** это так сделано? В какое время это произошло, при Пушкине или раньше, может, какая-то связь со старославянским есть?

Мне как-то стало любопытно, но я никак не могу понять, где бы об этом рассказывалось. Все просто постулируют правило, не рассказывая предыстории.

Никто не расскажет вкратце? Ссылки тоже интересны, если долго пересказывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  почему это так сделано? В какое время это произошло?
```

Смотря что произошло. Аккомодация (уподобление звуков разнородной артикуляции) происходила ещё в древнерусском языке согласно фонетическим законам сингармонизма. Твердые согласные должны сочетаться с гласными непереднего (среднего, заднего) ряда, а мягкие – с гласными переднего ряда.

См. http://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?lsnid=519&mode=lesson

В др/рус. текстах 12-13 в. буквой *и* обозначались (i, i(j), (j)ь, ь(j)>, буквой *ы* - (у, ъ(j), у (j)>составители славянской азбуки признавали их (ъj, ьj) равными фонемами (ы, и) и не различали их на письме.

См. http://dereksiz.org/1-russkij-yazik-v-sovremennom-slavyanskom-mire-osnovnie-proble.html?page=5

Исторически же мы можем употреблять понятие «русский язык» лишь применительно к 14-15 в. в связи с началом образования государства Московского. До этого он недифференцированно входил, наряду с украинским и белорусским, в древнерусский язык в качестве его диалектов.

Так что ЭТО происходило уже в 14-15 веках и при Пушкине тоже. А почему - почитайте подробно:

http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/fonetika-fonologia/zvuki-rechi-fonetich-processi/izmenenie-glasnih-zvukov-v-zavisimosti-ot-tverdosti-myagkosti-sosednih-soglasnih-zvukov/3997/?n=3997&q=463

https://lisovitskaya.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/populyarno-ob-istokah-principov-russkoj-grafiki-i-orfografii/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, очень подробно и обстоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке существует несколько принципов  орфографии: морфологический, фонетический, традиционный, дифферинцированный.

Написание ы вместо и после русских приставок обусловлено фонетическим принципом письма(слова пишутся точно так же, как слышатся). Ср. другие слова, которые пишутся в соответствии с этим принципом письма.

**инфаркт — пред-ынфарктный;
индивидуальный — над-ындивидуальный;
инициативный — без-ынициативный;
искусный — без-ыскусный;**

Эти написания являются целиком и полностью фонетическими. Соблюдение морфологического принципа орфографии привело бы в данном случае к нарушению другого важнейшего принципа нашего письма - слогового принципа графики . Этот принцип предполагает, что в качестве единицы чтения и письма в русском языке выступает графический слог, т. е. что " сочетание согласной и гласной букв представляет цельный графический элемент, буквосочетание, обе части которого взаимно обусловлены: как гласные, так и согласные буквы пишутся и читаются с учетом соседних букв " **[ Иванова В.Ф. Современный русский язык. Графика и орфография. М., 1976. С. 76-77 ].**

В соответствии с этим принципом буква **и , следующая за согласной, требует произносить эту согласную как мягкую.**

> *Однако согласно современной произносительной норме смягчения твердой согласной на конце приставок перед начальным и корня в действительности не происходит **(ср. при ди - пре ды дущий, о би да - о бы грать ).***

Comment: "Существует несколько принциппов", "современной норме" -- а когда эти принципы появились? В эпоху Пушкина, раньше? Почему например, на украинском 'передісторія', а у нас 'предыстория'? Возможно, это со старославянского идёт? Прямо говоря -- это просто расширенный ответ о том, как надо писать, а не почему так сложилось и когда.

Comment: После реформы русской орфографии 1918 года буква і была убрана из языка, т. к. по звучанию она полностью совпадала с буквой и. Что касается слов 'передісторія', а у нас 'предыстория', то здесь наблюдается полногласие и неполногласие. Неполногласие пришло из старославянского языка. В некоторых словах оно утратилось.